# Updating Inputs Based on Previous Input in Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny

I have a dataset on which I want to apply 3 filters (City, Type and Name of Universities) consecutively. I want to apply a sequential filtering such that when I choose a specific City, other select inputs (Type and Name of universities) be updated accordingly.

I have tried many variations also through stackoverflow solution, however, unable to come up with a solution.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(readxl)

data <-  read_excel("foreign_students_by_nationality_2021_2022.xlsx")
colnames(data) <- c("name", "type", "city", "country", "male", "female", "total")
data$male <- as.numeric(data$male)
data$female <- as.numeric(data$female)
data$total <- as.numeric(data$total)
print(str(data))


# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Foreign Students in Turkish Universities"),
    theme = shinythemes::shinytheme("superhero"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput("uni_city",
                        "Select a City",
                        choices = data$city %>% unique() %>% sort()
                          ),
            selectInput("uni_type", 
                        "Select a University Type", 
                        choices = ""
                        ),
            selectInput("uni_name", 
                        "Select a University", 
                        choices = ""
                        )
        ),

        
        mainPanel(
           plotOutput("barplot")
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  type_var <- reactive({data %>% filter(city == input$uni_city) %>% 
      select(type) %>% unique()})
    
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, "uni_type", choices = type_var())
  })
  
  name_var <- reactive({data %>% filter(city == input$uni_city, type == input$uni_type) %>% 
      select(name) %>% unique() %>% sort()})
  
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, "uni_name", choices = name_var())
  })
  
  output$barplot <- renderPlot({
   
    highest_country <- 
      data %>% 
      filter(city == input$uni_city,
             type == input$uni_type,
             name == input$uni_name) %>% 
      group_by(country) %>% 
      summarise(female = sum(female), 
                male = sum(male), 
                total = sum(total)) %>% 
      arrange(desc(total)) %>% 
      pivot_longer(c(-country, -total), names_to = "gender", values_to = "value") %>% 
      slice_max(total, n = 20)
    
    
    
    ggplot(highest_country, 
           aes(x = reorder(country, total), 
               y = value, 
               fill = gender)
    ) +
      geom_col() +
      coord_flip() + 
      labs(x = "Nationality", y = "Number of Students") 
    
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Hi just answered almost the same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74592618/how-to-organize-selectizeinput-fields-with-dependecies-on-each-other/74600121#74600121 please have look there and see if it helps

Comment: and also please add some data that we can try with `dput` is goof function to share small data examples with

Comment: you could just try replacing `select` with `pull` in your reacvtive `*_var` statments